# Entity Framework : Invalid column name *_ID1, Part 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a new job, and I need to continue developing software that is already working.

The issue, and I've tried all similar posts, is that when I try to query a table, it tells me that there is an error with `UserId1`. The thing is that the field is `UserId`, and I don't understand where this name `UserId1` is being mapped.

**ERROR**

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'UserId1'.'
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Invalid column name 'UserId1'.
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at ...
```

I tried different ways to declare the foreign key as I saw in other post, but I could not make it work.

I am using the `scaffold` command to create the model.

The query is:

```
model = x.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.CompanyId, "IX_CompanyId");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.ExternalIdlHash, "IX_ExternalIdlHash");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId, "IX_UserId");

        entity.Property(e => e.Abn).HasColumnName("ABN");
        entity.Property(e => e.ExternalId).HasMaxLength(20);

        entity.Property(e => e.IsContractor)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(CONVERT([bit],(0)))");

        entity.Property(e => e.Tfn).HasColumnName("TFN");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Company)
            .WithMany(p => p.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.UserRoles_dbo.Companies_CompanyId");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.UserRoles_dbo.Users_UserId");
    });
```

Model class:

```
public partial class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public double? Rate { get; set; }
    public string? ExternalId { get; set; }
    public int? ExternalIdlHash { get; set; }
    public string? Abn { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public double? AwardRate { get; set; }
    public string? Tfn { get; set; }
    public bool? IsContractor { get; set; }

    public virtual Company? Company { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I've tried all similar posts. In fact, I copied the title from another post, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: "there is an error with UserId1" - always provide exact error messages when asking for help, not your paraphrase of them. Show the line of code that defines `x`